# Setting up Vue router in Vue2 using the script tag only.like angular 1.x router

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router

I need to set up vue router in my vue ja 2 application .I am not using vue cli just the cdn for vue Js .I am not able to find a way of how to set up vue router with cdn.can anyone suggest any documentation or the technique of how to achieve that ??
Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a bare bones example to help get going:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router@2.0.0/dist/vue-router.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app">
    <p><router-link to="/page1">Go to Page 1</router-link></p>
    <p><router-link to="/page2">Go to Page 2</router-link></p>
    <p><router-view></router-view></p>
</div>

<script>
    var PageTwoComponent = Vue.component('comp2',{
        template: '<p>Component Two</p>'
    })
    var PageOneComponent = Vue.component('comp1',{
        template: '<p>Component One</p>'
    })

    const routes = [
        {path: '/page1', component: PageTwoComponent},
        {path: '/page2', component: PageOneComponent}
    ]

    const router = new VueRouter({
        routes
    })

    var app = new Vue({
        router
    }).$mount('#app')

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @MarkM .That helped